# How to disable/reduce delay ack time on windows

Tags: c#, windows, tcp

I have a c# sdk which needs to use TcpClient, but the connection is using 200ms as delay ack time, but my server will retransmit the data in 100ms, so every time the server send a tcp data, it will do a retransmission.

So is there any idea to reduce the delay time? like reduce it to 40ms?

I know it's able to disable delay on linux by setting TCP_QUICKACK, but is there any way to disable the delay time or reduce the time on windows?

I see there is a registry entry on windows which can make reduce the delayed time, but it's set for network interface, I just wanna set for my program, and don't effect other programs.

I also tried NO_DELAY option, but this option seems to work for nagle, not delay ack, so it's not working for me.

Ok, I have to do an update to make sure you know my situation.

I do understand that delay ack is useful to reduce tcp package number when you are receiving lots of little packages on a connection.

But in my case, things are different, I have lots of connections, they might just do nothing, just hung on my server, and wait for message from server. To make sure the connection is alive, client will send a ping package to server every 30s(for example), and server will response a pong. And then client will do nothing.

So in my case, the pong response, which is sent from server is not acked in 100ms because windows will wait 200ms by default, and then my server think the package is lost, a retransmission is sent.

So, delay ack is not reducing package number, it's increasing package number.

Comment: TCP handles retransmissions under the hood so you don't have to - is there a reason you want to do this manually?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis I don't wanna waste the server's network. And the network is good since I can receive both packages on client side, just windows never return ack in 100ms, so my server think the package is lost, and do a retransmission.So I wanna avoid this retransmission.

Comment: RFC 1122 _recommends_ delaying ACK for up to 500ms to _reduce_ bandwith. So I still wonder why you want your server to assume a packet is lost after 100ms of silence. If you want to control retransmissions yourself you might want to reconsider the use of TCP.